# Convert RGBA values to hex color code

Tags: java, colors, hex, argb

I have some sliders in my application that allows the user to change ARGB colors, however I need to convert these values to a hex value like 0xff000000, which is solid black.

This is what I have so far:

```
protected int toHex(Color col) {
    String as = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getAlpha()));
    String rs = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getRed()));
    String gs = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getGreen()));
    String bs = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getBlue()));
    String hex = "0x" + as + rs + gs + bs;
    return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
}

private static final String pad(String s) {
    return (s.length() == 1) ? "0" + s : s;
}
```

However upon getting the Integer value like below, I get a NumberFormatException for input string: "0xccffffff":

```
int color = toHex(new Color(153f, 153f, 153f, 0.80f));
```

Any ideas on how to get this to an Integer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Color parameters must be floats between 1f and 0f. So this is a valid color:

```
int color = toHex(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));
```

Which is white.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Got it sorted now. I'm using Slick for my font stuff and I've now switched the Color to java.awt.Color.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are including alpha values.
So your maximum color code is `#FFFFFFFF` (8 digits).

The method `Integer.parseInt` will let you parse value from `-0x80000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`. In order to get your value `0xCC999999` from it, you would have to negate the value and input `-0x33666667` - which is of course not useful at all.

The clunky but stable workaround is using `Long`.

```
(int) Long.parseLong(text, 16)
```