# Change from ARGB Color to RRGGBB color

Tags: java, android, colors, argb

I want to set the values: Red: 0.910 green: 0.969 blue: 0.996 alpha: 1.0
I get color as:

```
int color=Color.argb(1.0,0.910,0.969,0.996)
```

but this doesn't work.

I want to get the value in hex color as #FF00FF. Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get Hex values

```
protected int toHex(Color col) {
        String as = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getAlpha()));
        String rs = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getRed()));
        String gs = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getGreen()));
        String bs = pad(Integer.toHexString(col.getBlue()));
        String hex = "0x" + as + rs + gs + bs;
        return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    }

    private static final String pad(String s) {
        return (s.length() == 1) ? "0" + s : s;
    }
```

eg : int color = toHex(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));

Here's the link I refered to 
[Convert RGBA values to hex color code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459879/convert-rgba-values-to-hex-color-code?rq=1)

Related Links:

[How to convert a color integer to a hex String in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android?rq=1)